# Is it possible to install openmodelica in a linux server without the GUI?

Tags: linux, modelica, jupyterhub, openmodelica

I run a jupyterhub server with python, julia, sagemath and others.

I wanted to share notebooks running OpenModelica models from jupyter notebooks using OMPython.

And it works, and it wasn't hard.

But I had to install openmodelica using the instructions for a ubuntu server:

https://openmodelica.org/download/download-linux

and I got hundreds of packages installed, including a full desktop environment for running OMEdit and such.

Is it possible to install a bare version of openmodelica in a linux server with just the command line executable?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apt-get install omc
```

Instead of

```
apt-get install openmodelica
```

This will be a quite bare version of OpenModelica without Qt dependencies